# MySQL Repeating Events

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database-design, pattern-matching

I am building an java application that will find repeating events from MySQL database.

My table looks like this:

```
| **EventID** | **Device** | **Level** | **TimeStamp** |
     (id)           001         40%     1/18/2016 4:50:20
```

An event is like : Device **001** turned to level **40%** at **1/18/2016 4:50:20**

How do I look up events like:

Device A gets turned to **around** level 36% at **around** 7:30:00 on every weekdays;

Or

Device B gets turned to **around** level 90% at **around** 15:30:00 on every Wednesday night;

Notice that level and time are not final (that's why it's around) for the events.  Does MySQL have ways to look up events and return time intervals and level intervals? Because I know it will be bad performance if I run something like:

```
For (all devices) {

 For (time 00:00:00 to time 23:59:59) {

      For (level 0% to 100%) {

            //SELECT based on level intervals and time intervals

      }
 }
}
```

The above approach will also be biased because the time and level intervals are preset here. So for example, if events always happen around 7:40, and I do intervals between 7:20 and 7:40, I won't find as many events. Same for levels.

Comment: You need to decide what "around" means to your client. Read about BETWEEN. PS Besides "around" you must decide what "every" mean--for dates with events or dates on the calendar? All dates in a table or in a range of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has no direct tool for such.

First, decide what type of precision makes sense for your application.  For example, does "about 40%" mean 39.9 to 40.1?  Or 35 to 45?  Or something else?  Ditto for times -- is a 20 minute window precise enough?  Or should it be 1 minute or 1 hour.

Then fold.  That is for "daily" ignore the day and sum over time of day.  For "weekday", ignore weekend days.

And double sum...  FLOOR(value/10) gives you an integer that is different for each regular 10-unit ranges.  FLOOR((value+5)/10) gives you an integer for 10-unit intervals, but shifted by 5 units.  Lost?  Let me approach this from another point of view...

If there are a cluster of readings 17,18,18,19,19,19,20,21,22,23.  Grouping by the first FLOOR would give

- integer=1, count=6 (17..19), midpoint=15; and
- integer=2, count=4 (20..23), midpoint=25.

The Second FLOOR would lump all those together and find

- count=10, midpoint=20.

The largest count is 10, corresponding to a midpoint of 20.  So, wouldn't you say there is a cluster "around 20", not two clusters, one around 15, another around 25?

Anyway, that is how I would discover the clusters.  I would pick only the top few counts, toss the rest, and combining any overlapping or adjacent clusters.

The "units" above can be percentages, times of day, days of week, whatever makes sense.

How many "clusters" to shoot for?  Well, I am fascinated with the [80-20 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).  It predicts that 80% of the items will be clustered around 20% of the units.  Given that, stop scanning for midpoints after 20%.

If you get the 'precision' wrong the first time, change it and start over.